# kannel provides mclass=0 flash messages but it does not support for UCS2 messages(like arabic, hindi)

Tags: flash, sms, kannel

For English flash messages, mclass=0 works properly, but when I am sending Hindi or Arabic Flash message with mclass=0,coding=2 & charset=UTF-16BE, it get delivered into Inbox.

Please suggest how to send non english messages in flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the compatibility of the phone. The parameters are fine for sending flash messages.

Comment: thanks for answering. I ran into the same problem and it helped it.